# IE Chrome Frame Full Screen

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, fullscreen, google-chrome-frame

I have a working implementation of full screen working for Safari, Firefox, and Google Chrome.  From what I have read it should work for ie with google chrome frame but when I click the full screen button I created nothing happens.  Any ideas?  Is it not yet supported?

```
$('#enable_fullscreen').click ->
  calculate_presentation_font_size(height)
  if docElm.requestFullscreen
    docElm.requestFullscreen()
  else if docElm.mozRequestFullScreen
    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen()
  else if docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen
    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen()
```

Putting an alert in the "webkitRequestFullScreen" if statement shows that it does go to this condition in chrome frame but docElem.webkitrequestFullScreen() is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've build it and made it work from this examples. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode

The only things I can see missing from your code for the webkit condition is the parameter "Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT" to the webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT)

Unfortunately the main problem of chrome frame is the communication with the IE window that literally behave like a difficult child ;-)

For IE you can open a popup window in fullscreen mode by directly calling document.location.href for the source it will open the current page your are on

```
window.open(document.location.href, 'myAppfullscreen', 'fullscreen=1');
```

Comment: This is not working for me.  Are you using full screen in IE with Chrome Frame and it is working?

Comment: Where did you read it should work in IE with chrome frame?  From what I'm aware this is not supported in IE even with chrome frame. You best bet for IE is to open a popup window on fullscreen mode. Sorry this is not what you where looking for!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Funny enough I just have to fix the same things for the app I'm working on. I have a button on the UI that trigger fullscreen and the icon toggle I had to change the toggle state of the button to detect if the app is open inside of a popup window. Let me know if you need more help I should have the code sorted by day end.