# How to enable IE full-screen feature like firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

I looked following articles and jquery plugins

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/

http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

http://xme.im/display-fullscreen-website-using-javascript

http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/

http://jquery.pupunzi.com/questions/696/ie-containerplus-full-screen

[IE Chrome Frame Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539107/ie-chrome-frame-full-screen)

But couldnt find.

All those major articles refereed, but  I couldn't find any article which directly talking about IE full-screen feature,
Any one found workaround to the same?

I tried W3C proposal

```
// W3C Proposal
element.requestFullscreen();
document.exitFullscreen();
```

**UPDATED**
My expectation is, I have an image carousel, I need to show current selected image to show in full screen, seems to IE doesn't support, I plan to use jQuery model window(without jQuery UI). Just as the [example](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464332/internet-explorer-full-screen-mode 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript

Those two articles from SO will help you.

Answer (score 7):

sheelpriy answer is good with a small change, successfully tested on chrome, firefox, ie, safari and opera (all last version)

```
//HTML Button : <a href="#" id="fullscreen">Fullscreen</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Get element id "fullscreen"
    var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("fullscreen"); 

    //Activate click listener
    fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

        //Toggle fullscreen off, activate it
        if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {
            if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
                document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
            } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
            } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen(); // IE
            }

        //Toggle fullscreen on, exit fullscreen
        } else {

            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://caniuse.com/fullscreen) the fullscreen API is not supported in IE. There seem to be no information on whether this is something that will be supported by IE11 either.

According to MDN's [article on fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode) it seems that this technique is still be very much experimental for most browsers.

Comment: Actually the IE11 column is grey, which suggests that there is no information available yet. Therefore I doubt it's support is certain for that version.

Comment: @Smamatti Good catch, I have so lousy colors on my laptop, it looked green when I looked at it quickly. Thanks for correcting me, I've updated my answer!

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Yes I checked the article, seems to no luck, lets try :) Thanks.

Comment: the fullscreen API is supported in IE11. Currently with ms prefix, but that could change before final release. Source: http://fremycompany.com/BG/2013/Internet-Explorer-11-rsquo-s-leaked-build-395/

Answer (score 3):

[Internet Explorer full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464332/internet-explorer-full-screen-mode)

[Set window to fullscreen (REAL fullscreen; F11 functionality) by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript)

Those two articles from SO will help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function max() {
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

this will solve all your problems
expand is the id of button used for fullscreen

```
var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("expand"); 
fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (mediaPlayer.requestFullscreen) {
                mediaPlayer.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (mediaPlayer.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                mediaPlayer.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
            } else if (mediaPlayer.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                mediaPlayer.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
            }
            else if (mediaPlayer.msRequestFullscreen) {
                mediaPlayer.msRequestFullscreen(); // IE
            }
        });
```

p.s. will link would be a great help for you. : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254939(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Switcching fullscreen via scripts is Impossible in IE10 and below untill you don't tweak its security setting as present under -

```
Tools->Internet Options->Security tab->click Custom Level button ->
find "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe." option -> change it to Enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Take from the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and modified because they have ugly coding practices that will snap you in the heel when you minify)

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('fullscreen-toggle');
someElement.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var divObj = document.body;  //change to whatever element you want

    if (divObj.requestFullscreen){
        if (document.fullScreenElement) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();       
        } else {
          divObj.requestFullscreen();
        }   
    }   

    else if (divObj.msRequestFullscreen){
        if (document.msFullscreenElement) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else {
            divObj.msRequestFullscreen();
        }           
    }

    else if (divObj.mozRequestFullScreen){
        if (document.mozFullScreenElement) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else {
          divObj.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }

    else if (divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen){
        if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
          } else {
          divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }   
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

vidWha is the id of my video element.

full-screen is the id of my full-screen button.

this code is working on all the browsers.Tested.

```
var video = document.getElementById('vidWha');
var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById('full-screen');

// Event listener for the full-screen button
fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
}else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
}else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
}else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
    video.msRequestFullscreen(); // IE
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real functional example for Opera and Chrome since they have the same API. IE and Safari does not support it.

`addEventListener` is useless on objects that already have events, that's why it's called `Object.addEventListener`.

For a DIV object, `mediv.onmouseX = function () {code ...}` is more than enough; no need for `mediv.addEventListener` since the `div` object already has a mouse event.

For fullscreen check this example:

```
function mefull(iffull){
var isfullscreenelement = typeof(document.fullscreenElement)=='object';

if(!isfullscreenelement || isfullscreenelement=="undefined"){
    alert('Message !');
    return;
}

if(iffull){
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();

//your code here......

}else{
if (document.exitFullscreen) {
document.exitFullscreen();

//Yourcode here......

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I review what I said above (0_0)

After a lot of research and testing here is a script that works very well on IE, EDGE, CHROME, FIREFOX and OPERA. It does not work on SAFARI version 5.1. I hope this will help you... 
to test it create a html button and call the function

Set Full :

```
 setfullscreen(true);
```

supr full :

```
 setfullscreen(false);
```

*** this script donot require addEventListner.

```
var ensuredoc = null;  //reg your actual document is JS
function setfullscreen(isetting){

var domfull = (typeof(document.fullscreenElement)=='object')?1: 
(typeof(document.msFullscreenElement)=='object')?2: 
(typeof(document.mozFullScreenElement)=='object')?3: 
(typeof(document.webkitFullscreenElement)=='object')?4:0;

if(isetting){

if(domfull >0){ ensuredoc =document; }

var docE=document.documentElement;

                    if(domfull ==1){
                    docE.requestFullscreen();   
                    }else if(domfull ==2){
                    docE.msRequestFullscreen();
                    }else if(domfull ==3){
                    docE.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    }else if(domfull ==4){
                    docE.webkitRequestFullscreen();                     
                    }
 }else{
                    if(domfull==1){
                        if((typeof 
 ensuredoc.exitFullscreen)=='function') 
 {ensuredoc.exitFullscreen();
                        }else if((typeof 
 ensuredoc.cancelFullScreen)=='function') 
 {ensuredoc.cancelFullScreen();};   
                    }else if(domfull==2){
                    ensuredoc.msExitFullscreen();
                    }else if(domfull==3){
                    ensuredoc.mozCancelFullScreen();
                    }else if(domfull==4){
                    ensuredoc.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                    }
  }

  }
```

if you want to detect keyboard usage for a DIV object just add a simple code

```
var mediv = document.getElementById('mediv');
mediv.onkeyup = function(){ if(condition) {setfullscreen(false);}}
```

** I forgot to tell you that EDGE uses WEBKIT. Chrome uses the DOM to activate the screen but 'exitFullscreen' to exit

Answer (score 0):

When the browser changes to fullscreen and the user presses the ESCAPE key, it does not return the key event.

The solution is to use a timer to detect whether a change takes place on a DIV or other object.

We store in a variable a true or false value of a button that changes to fullscreen

We start the timer and run the code only if the size has changed. Example...

```
 var buttonclick = false;
 var MeInterval = null;

 function timerscreen(){
      if(buttonclicked){
           if(objectdiv.offsetHeight < screen.availHeight){
                 your code here.....

           //end timer
           clearInterval(MeInterval);
           }
      }
 }

 objectdiv.onmouseup(){
      buttonclicked = !buttonclicked;
      if(buttonclicked) MeInterval= setInterval(timerscreen, 1000);
 }
```