# document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11, fullscreen

I am trying to go fullscreen using document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen() on ie11. It returns undefined.

Also

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ember715"); 
elem.msRequestFullscreen()
```

returns undefined on ie11.
P.S- elem.requestFullscreen() does the job in chrome so elem is properly defined.
I have borrowed the idea from
 [How to enable IE full-screen feature like firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503016/how-to-enable-ie-full-screen-feature-like-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: `msRequestFullscreen` is a function, so `document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen === true` should be evaluating to false. `document.documentElement.msFullscreenEnabled === true` could evaluate to true...

Comment: Have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: So, a function call will return undefined if it is a void function (i.e., it doesn't return anything). This is normal. Does `requestFullScreen()` return something other than undefined in Chrome?

Comment: in chrome it changes it to fulsscreen while returning-
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a test with the code below. I tested it with IE 11 and it works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the video in fullscreen mode.</p>
<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Video in Fullscreen Mode</button>
<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.</p>

<video width="100%" controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="sample.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
/* Get the element you want displayed in fullscreen */ 
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");

/* Function to open fullscreen mode */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>

<p>Note: Internet Explorer 10 and earlier does not support fullscreen mode.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

[HTML DOM requestFullscreen() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_requestfullscreen.asp)

Comment: Yes this code is working on ie 11. 
My code is not working in ie11- I have correctly replaced 
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo"); 
with
var elem = document.getElementById("ember715");
note I have tried my code (with the above replacement ) in chrome and it is working and hence I am sure that I have selected the elem correctly.

Comment: If possible, can you post your HTML along with your JS code? So that we can also try to make a test with your code to see the results. It may help to narrow down the issue.